# interfaces with getters and setters in go language

Tags: go

I'm new to go language and having problems specifying an interface to a struct from different files with a getter and setter.

---

**Source**

*src/github.com/user/interfaces*

```
package interfaces

type IFoo interface {
    Name() string
    SetName(name string)
}
```

*src/github.com/user/foo*

```
package foo

import "github.com/user/interfaces"

type Foo struct {
    name string
}

func (f *interfaces.IFoo) SetName(name string) {
    f.name = name
}

func (f IFoo) Name() string {
    return f.name
}
```

If I change method signature of struct Foo to the following then the `import "github.com/user/interfaces"` becomes unused.

```
func (f *Foo) SetName(name string) {
    f.name = name
}

func (f Foo) Name() string {
    return f.name
}
```

---

**Test**

```
test/github.com/user/foo/foo_test.go

package foo

import (
    "testing"
    "github.com/user/foo"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/user/interfaces"
)

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    foo := foo.Foo{}

    fmt.Println(interfaces.IFoo(foo))
}
```

**Question:** How can I specify the IFoo interface to the Foo struct and have the unit test pass in the above example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I specify the IFoo interface to the Foo struct

You don't.  In Go, interface implementation is implicit.  See https://tour.golang.org/methods/10.

Which is to say, if Foo implements all of the methods of the IFoo interface, it implements the interface.  You don't need to "tell" the struct that it is an IFoo.

All you have to do is

```
func (f *Foo) SetName(name string) {
    f.name = name
}

func (f Foo) Name() string {
    return f.name
}
```

And then in your test you can do:

```
test/github.com/user/foo/foo_test.go

package foo

import (
    "testing"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/user/interfaces"
)

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    var foo interfaces.IFoo = &Foo{}
    foo.SetName("bar")
    fmt.Println(foo.Name())
}
```

Edit: Your test file should live in the same folder as the file it is testing, you should not have them all in a `test` folder.  That being said, if you want to keep the structure the same, you would need to make sure that your package name `foo` is not overwritten by your variable name `foo`, and then prefix `Foo{}` with `foo`:

```
test/github.com/user/foo/foo_test.go

package foo

import (
    "testing"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/user/interfaces"
    "github.com/user/foo"
)

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    var f interfaces.IFoo = &foo.Foo{}
    f.SetName("bar")
    fmt.Println(f.Name())
}
```

Comment: thanks for clearing up, it's clear to me about the implicit implementation, however, I'm having errors with your test part of the code. You can download the source code from question link for the exact answer. It's saying `unresolved Type Foo` for the first line of your `TestFoo` function

Comment: it might be because it had `import "github.com/user/foo"` when we were already in the foo package, I took it out and that should work.

Comment: Actually, wait... your filename says `test/github.com/user/foo/foo_test.go` - do you have everything in a folder called `test`?  If so, you should not, it foo_test.go should be in the same directory as foo.go

Comment: still `test/github.com/user/foo/foo_test.go:10: undefined: Foo`, mine #10, your line #11. yes my tests are in a different folder, please download dropbox to see the structure. https://www.dropbox.com/s/78sz2lxnly9dwyr/IFoo.zip?dl=0

Comment: I'm at work and filesharing sites are all blocked, so can't.  As I said, tests should not be in a different folder, they should live right next to the actual file.  Look at https://github.com/gorilla/mux and see how they structured it.

Comment: I moved the `foo_test` to `gitHub.com/user/foo/` and renamed testing var from `foo` to `f`, Error: `cannot use Foo literal (type Foo) as type interfaces.IFoo in assignment:
 Foo does not implement interfaces.IFoo (SetName method has pointer receiver)`. I request you kindly do a local test by copying code from my source file and compile the program, you'd see the problems.

Comment: I've uploaded to AWS s3 for your convenience https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/golangtest/ifoo.zip

Comment: See edit.  It says you have pointer receiver so you need to make your Foo{} an &Foo{} for it to implement the interface

Comment: yes, now it's compiling, there was something between the lines, required very fine touch and edit to it, don't know someone gave it a negative vote, do you see any problem with my question?

Comment: it even runs while I moved the test file to the test folder, i had to add an import to it. I read a lot on this but my complain now is I never saw anything related to assigning ampersand to an interface, where can I read more about it please? also please up vote my question.